# Is Stevie Wonder blind?

Tags: celebrities

According to [this lifehacker](http://theconcourse.deadspin.com/stevie-wonder-is-not-blind-the-evidence-1641795715?utm_source=recirculation&utm_medium=recirculation&utm_campaign=fridayAM) article, there is a group of "Stevie Wonder Truthers" who believe that Stevie Wonder is not actually blind.

Apparently, Boy George, in particular, said that Stevie Wonder was able to locate him in a room.

Is there any evidence that Stevie Wonder is legally blind, per the definition of [legal blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness#Legal_definition) in the United States?

Comment: I suppose one could look up his hospital birth records. The description of his retina being detached and the eye starved of oxygen before birth does not sound like something recoverable.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Do you have reason to imagine the man's medical records are public?

Comment: To help with notability: In the TV series "Jonathan Creek", an episode has a fictional Jazz musician Hewie Harper, who was blind until 8 years ago, but still pretends to be blind. http://www.jonathancreek.net/season2episode4.asp

Comment: @ChrisW: *shrug* It's a fairly distant premise, but such documentation seems to show up with some degree of regularity on those "Smoking Gun"-type sites all of the time. And that's pretty much the only way I can think of to provide an answer that's not just hearsay.

Comment: A blind person can locate any object with the help of the advanced technique called [echolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_echolocation).

Comment: Locating Boy George in a room with your eyes closed isn't hard. Just turn towards the loudest corner and there you go. [rimshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Library of Congress > National Disability Employment Awareness Month > Featured Profile: Stevie Wonder](http://www.loc.gov/disabilityawareness/profiles/wonder.html)

> Born in Saginaw, Michigan in 1950, Stevie Wonder became blind shortly after birth.

[The Biography Channel](http://www.thebiographychannel.co.uk/biographies/stevie-wonder.html)

> His first album, 'Little Stevie Wonder the 12 Year Old Genius', made the child a huge star, and gave Stevie a number one hit with single 'Fingertips'. The following year, he enrolled in the Michigan School for the Blind, where he studied classical piano.